# Can only use og:type "article" in like button

Tags: types, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I am creating a like button for my website, but in Firefox the comment box pops up and immediately disappears when clicked. The only time it works is if I set og:type=article.

Site has never had a button before but it says it has 19K likes. I assume that's from folks mentioning the site in Facebook. So does this mean a random Type has been set and I'm screwed now?

Test page http://phoebeallens.com/test2.html

Answer (score 0):

The root domain should have type = website or blog, all other pages should be article or something close to what they are.

SEE: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/#types  scroll down to websites.

Comment: Also you can change the url in your like button to reflect the actual url of the page.

<fb:like href="http://phoebeallens.com" send="false" layout="button_count" width="90" show_faces="false"></fb:like>

Comment: My question is why any Type except "Article" causes it to not work. I want it to be "website" and am only calling the page test2.html temporaraly. I do have it reflect the url of the root page. The problem is the popup comment box vanishes unless I use type=article.

Comment: Keep in mind you are trying to like a page that has no tags yet, on a different page. EG: your trying to like phoebeallens.com from phoebeallens.com/test2.html and the root has no tags.

 Set the og:tags on your root page then try to like.

if it is not the root of the domain the you can not use the type "website or blog".  Did you reLint the page after making your changes?
http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fphoebeallens.com%2Ftest2.html

Comment: Tags are being read from the root correctly. I reLint each time I change something. It works perfectly with Type=Article but popup vanishes with Website (using Firefox). It actually appears to work with IE. Anyway, no big deal. I just hate when things act flaky. Thanks.

Comment: Your Welcome,  when i first added OG:tags myself, i type'ed 11,000+ pages as website and started generating likes for each page.  On doing so each page created a facebook page which could be liked, which if liked would create a loop.  

at the end of my error, i had generated 774,000+ facebook pages with my 11,000 lol, i know your pain.

Comment: If firefox is not liking it, trying using full url in your button

<fb:like href=" http :// phoebeallens.com" ; send="false" layout="button_count" width="90" show_faces="false"></fb:like>